# How to enable instant app option in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-instant-apps

I am using the google pixel XL emulator with Google APIS 7.1.1, but I am not able to find enable instant app option in Google setting,

Comment: Some emulators with certain devices/builds won’t have instant app settings until you build an instant app to it.

Comment: Currently, Instant apps should be available in all countries now.

Comment: Any example app that can I see

Comment: You won’t be able to find live instant apps using the emulator, at least not as of now. You will need to find a device (5.0 or higher) that is supported by Instant Apps. Then you can search on Chrome for: “buzzfeed nifty” or “yummly recipes” and you should see an “instant” badge next to compatible links.

Answer (score 2):

To setup the emulator for Instant Apps, follow the instructions here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/setup.html#setup-emulator

The 7.1 emulator (x86, Google APIs but no Play Store) should work. Double check you are logged in with a Google account on the device and you will need to deploy one Instant App from Android Studio to the emulator to provision the device correctly.

Provisioning will ensure the right versions of all the components are on the device as well as send special flags that will override any reasons why Instant Apps won't run (eg. if you are in a country that is not launched).

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know where are you from, but Instant Apps feature is available only in some countries, here you have the list: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861#production

Comment: This might be the reason, I am from India is not on that list.

Comment: Anyway you can use an emulator, create one using this link https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/setup.html#setup-emulator and then deploy an app with instant-app feature on your emulator and that option will be available. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Google -> Instant apps. Move toggle to enable Instant Apps.

More info: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211?hl=en

Comment: I checked but there is no instant app option

Comment: Yes I checked with 8.0 and 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you signed in with your google account in the emulator?

Comment: Yes i logged in

Comment: Then it should show instant app option under Settings> Google> Instant App (right below Google Fit). I am using the emulator Pixel API_25 and it is working absolutely fine. If still you didn't find it useful kindly update me the configs of the emulator you are using.

Comment: I   am using nexus_6P_API_26.

Comment: I am using the same and it is working fine here. Check the SDK must be properly installed for API 26